# How to efficiently syntax

Tags: python, syntax-highlighting

I wrote some code. I realized when I wanted to expand the code below, it would make the syntax wasteful.
how to make it efficient?

```
a = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e']
b = int(input("Number of digit:\n"))
#This is for 1 digit printed
if b == 1:
   for i in a:
        print(i)
#This is for 2 digit printed
elif b == 2:
    for i in a:
        for j in a:
           print(i,j)

#This is for 3 digit printed
    elif b == 2:
        for i in a:
            for j in a:
                for k in a:
                   print(i,j,k)
```

Comment: Please explain what does *I want to make it 2 digits* mean?

Comment: Can you please explain your personal definition of the word "syntax".

Comment: i've edit it. how to efficiently the code please all answer i respect it :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `itertools` to generalize this for any `b` as follows:

```
import itertools

a = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e']
b = int(input("Number of digit:\n"))

for t in itertools.product(a, repeat=b):
    print(*t)
```

If you instead want to save the tuples in a list, you can do:

```
vals = list(itertools.product(a, repeat=b))
```

Comment: can you explain what thas " * " mean before t:)

Comment: Yes, the `*t` in `print(*t)` simply inserts an iterable into the argument list.  For instance, if `t` is the tuple `("a", "b", "c")`, then `print(*t)` is the same as `print("a", "b", "c")`.  This will give you the exact same output format that you have in your code.

Comment: @Tom Karzes without `*` it is working fine , with `*` giving below error `TypeError: join() takes exactly one argument (3 given)` with b=3

Comment: @PIG You're confusing two different answers. `print(*t)` works. There is no `join` in my solution. My solution, the one you commented on, is the one *directly above* these comments. You were looking at a different solution, and trying to add `*` to it. You probably tried something like `print(" ".join(*t))`, which of course doesn't work. `print(*t)` does work..

Answer (score 0):

`itertools.product` would simplify your code:

```
import itertools

a = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e']
b = int(input("Number of digit:\n"))

for i in itertools.product(a, repeat=b):
    print(" ".join(i))
```

Answer (score 0):

This is probably the way to go, I think. This will print the way you want your elements to be combined. Read more about [itertools](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html)

```py
import itertools
a = ['a','b','c']
num = 2

if num == 2:
  a = [x for x in itertools.product(a, a)]

print(a)  # prints this : [('a', 'a'), ('a', 'b'), ('a', 'c'), ('b', 'a'), ('b', 'b'), ('b', 'c'), ('c', 'a'), ('c', 'b'), ('c', 'c')]
```